# Sending with XBEE S1 + api com.rapplogic.xbee

Tags: send, xbee

I work with com.rapplogic.xbee api and XBEE S1.

I want to send this array :

```
  payload = [-84, -19, 0, 5, 117, 114, 0, 19, 91, 76, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 79, 98, 106, 101, 99, 116, 59, -112, -50, 88, -97, 16, 115, 41, 108, 2, 0, 0, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 2, 116, 0, 4, 50, 51, 52, 53, 117, 114, 0, 3, 91, 91, 68, -57, -83, 11, -1, 100, 103, -1, 69, 2, 0, 0, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 2, 117, 114, 0, 2, 91, 68, 62, -90, -116, 20, -85, 99, 90, 30, 2, 0, 0, 120, 112, 0, 0, 0, 3, 63, -16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 117, 113, 0, 126, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 63, -11, -123, 30, -72, 81, -21, -123, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

form coordinator to End Device, using this method:

```
public static  void Send(XBeeAddress64 destination, int[] payload) throws XBeeException{

      int errors = 0;        int ackErrors = 0;         int ccaErrors = 0;        int purgeErrors = 0;        long now; 

      TxRequest64 tx = new TxRequest64(destination,payload); 

      now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      FindEndDevice.cordinnator.sendAsynchronous(tx);
      XBeeResponse response = null;
      while (true) {    
          System.out.println("***************************J'envoi les données to End Device ******************");
          // blocks until we get response
      response = FindEndDevice.cordinnator.getResponse();
      if (response.getApiId() != ApiId.TX_STATUS_RESPONSE) {
          log.debug("*** expected tx status but received " + response);
      } else {
          if (((TxStatusResponse) response).getFrameId() != tx.getFrameId()) {
              throw new RuntimeException("**** frame id does not match");
          }
          if (((TxStatusResponse) response).getStatus() != TxStatusResponse.Status.SUCCESS) {
              errors++;
              if (((TxStatusResponse) response).isAckError()) {
                    ackErrors++;
              } else if (((TxStatusResponse) response).isCcaError()) {
                      ccaErrors++;
              } else if (((TxStatusResponse) response).isPurged()) {
                      purgeErrors++;
              }
              log.debug("*** Tx status failure with status: " + ((TxStatusResponse) response).getStatus());
          } else {
              // success
               log.debug("*** Success Envoi. errors is " + errors + ", in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now) + ", ack errors "
                                          + ackErrors + ", ccaErrors " + ccaErrors + ", purge errors " + purgeErrors);
          }
          break;
      }
      }//fin while
      System.out.println("**** Fin Send********");
}
```

but that its not working, knowing that when I put payload = {-84, -19, 0, 5} my message is well received by my End Device !
Any Idea ??

Comment: Payload looks kind of large -- are you sure you're not exceeding the maximum packet size?  Try testing with a small array to ensure your code is working.  You could probably add some error checking around the creation of the `tx` object or `sendAsynchronous()` call.